# Изменить позицию canvas html5

Tags: javascript, html5, canvas

Возможно ли изменить позицию фигуры в канвасе, без того, чтоб все очищать или поверх этой фигуры налаживать новую? Позиция самой фигуры заранее известно и нужно ее двигать в нужном направление, но помимо этой фигуры, там присутствуют ряд других. И не хотелось бы все очищать и заново перерисовывать.

Код примерно такой:

```
...
ctx.fillStyle = '#f50';
ctx.fillRect( 20, 20, 100, 50 );
...
```

Comment: Без очистки холста никак, нужно перерисовывать все объекты

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Возможно ли изменить позицию фигуры в канвасе, без того, чтоб все очищать

нет

> не хотелось бы все очищать и заново перерисовывать

тут есть как минимум два варианта:

### 1) использовать два канваса

так как элемент канвас, и то, что в нём рисуется, может быть прозрачным - можно наложить один канвас поверх другого. и в том, что сверху, рисовать передвигаемые объекты.

```js
let html = (template, ...substitutions) => String.raw(template, ...substitutions);
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
    const W = 400;
    const H = 400;
    document.body.setAttribute('style', 'background-color: #eaffea;');
    document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', html `
        <canvas id="back" width="${W}" height="${H}" style="position:fixed; top:40px; left:40px; border:solid 1px grey;"></canvas>
        <canvas id="front" width="${W}" height="${H}" style="position:fixed; top:40px; left:40px; border:solid 1px grey;"></canvas>
    `);
    let back = document.getElementById('back');
    let back_ctx = back.getContext('2d');
    let front = document.getElementById('front');
    let front_ctx = front.getContext('2d');
    drawCircle(back_ctx, [120, 20], [100, 100]);
    let xy = [0, 0];
    let wh = [100, 100];
    setInterval(() => {
        Promise
            .resolve(front_ctx)
            .then(clearCircle)
            .then(ctx => drawCircle(ctx, xy, wh))
            .then(move);
    }, 20);
    function clearCircle(ctx) {
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, W, H);
        return ctx;
    }
    function drawCircle(ctx, [x, y], [w, h]) {
        ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(125,125,125,0.5)';
        ctx.fillRect(x, y, w, h);
        return ctx;
    }
    let q = true;
    function move() {
        if (q) {
            xy[0]++;
            if (xy[0] >= (W - 100))
                q = !q;
        }
        else {
            xy[0]--;
            if (xy[0] <= 0)
                q = !q;
        }
    }
});
```

### 2) делать "скриншот" фонового изображения

если фоновое изображение рисуется редко - можно сделать картинку и подставлять картинку, вместо повторения вычислений и отрисовок

```js
let html = (template, ...substitutions) => String.raw(template, ...substitutions);
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
    const W = 400;
    const H = 400;
    document.body.setAttribute('style', 'background-color: #eaffea;');
    document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', html `
        <canvas id="back" width="${W}" height="${H}" style="position:fixed; top:40px; left:40px; border:solid 1px grey;"></canvas>
    `);
    let back = document.getElementById('back');
    let back_ctx = back.getContext('2d');
    drawCircle(back_ctx, [120, 20], [100, 100]);
    let data = back_ctx.getImageData(0, 0, W, H);
    function restoreData(ctx) {
        ctx.putImageData(data, 0, 0);
        return ctx;
    }
    let xy = [0, 0];
    setInterval(() => {
        Promise
            .resolve(back_ctx)
            .then(clearCircle)
            .then(restoreData)
            .then(ctx => drawCircle(ctx, xy, [100, 100]))
            .then(move);
    }, 20);
    function clearCircle(ctx) {
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, W, H);
        return ctx;
    }
    function drawCircle(ctx, [x, y], [w, h]) {
        ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(125,125,125,0.5)';
        ctx.fillRect(x, y, w, h);
        return ctx;
    }
    let q = true;
    function move() {
        if (q) {
            xy[0]++;
            if (xy[0] >= (W - 100))
                q = !q;
        }
        else {
            xy[0]--;
            if (xy[0] <= 0)
                q = !q;
        }
    }
});
//# sourceMappingURL=index.js.map
```